# Google Sheets Query to return conditional Select?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

Complete SQL amateur here. I have a google sheet where the user enters data in the format `A[B or C]`. So using this table:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| A     | B           | C           |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Apple | Red         | Crunchy     |
| Pear  |             | Crunchy     |
| Lemon |             |             |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

..I would expect the following returns:

input `apple[red]` return `Apple Red`

input `apple[crunchy]` return `Apple Crunchy`

So basically only `B` or `C` are returned in addition to `A` depending on which column the match has occurred in. In reality `crunchy` could be in either column `B` or `C` (but not both).

I have this so far:

`Select A, B, C where 
    UPPER(H) matches '.*(?:^|,|,\s)"&REGEXEXTRACT(Q3,"^[^\[]+")&"(?:,\s|,|$).*' 
    and B matches '"&REGEXEXTRACT(Q3, "\[(\w+)\]")&"' limit 1`

But obviously its not working as I want and a match returns `A B C` as expected.

So I guess my questions are can you conditionally return column based on the match and also whats the best way of using `OR` for the `B` and `C` match? I tried just putting `and B or C matches` but that fails. I guess you can just write out a whole other line like `B matches '"&REGEXEXTRACT(Q3, "\[(\w+)\]")&"' or C matches '"&REGEXEXTRACT(Q3, "\[(\w+)\]")&"'` but its all starting to get quite convoluted and I'm guessing there is an easier way.

One other thing I'm wondering is if there is a way of making both `B` and `C` optional so in the above if the user inputs `apple` only `Apple` is returned. I was going to do this with a sheets `if` and 2 queries depending on whether `[]` is present but wondered if its doable in one SQL statement.

Thanks for any help. Won't have any hair left with all this head scratching!

Answer (score 1):

OK so how would you do this in Google sheets? There are two issues with the Google Sheets Query that make it a bit awkward

(1) No unions

(2) You can't return an empty set - it gives you an error message instead.

The two separate queries would look like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A:B,A:A&"["&B:B&"]"},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3='"&F1&"'"))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A:A,C:C,A:A&"["&C:C&"]"},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3='"&H1&"'"))
```

where F1 and H1 contain the required inputs.

To combine them, you'd have to put in IFERROR statements like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(query({A:B,A:A&"["&B:B&"]"},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3='"&J1&"'"),iferror(query({A:A,C:C,A:A&"["&C:C&"]"},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3='"&H1&"'"),"")))
```

This is assuming that only one of the queries delivers a result.

Comment: Thanks tom. Think I'm going to try it without query first. I find it a complete nightmare to work with! If that fails I'll give this a shot but I'll need to sit with it to work out whats going on

Comment: I think you're right, Google queries don't seem to help much with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, why not just:

```
create table mytable (A text, B text, C text);
insert into mytable values ('Apple', 'Red', 'Crunchy'), ('Pear', null, 'Crunchy'), ('Lemon', null, null);
select * from mytable;

-- Example 1: input = apple[red]
select a, b from mytable where upper(a || '[' || b || ']') = upper('apple[red]')
union all 
  select a, c from mytable where upper(a || '[' || c || ']') = upper('apple[red]');

-- Example 2: Same query different input = apple[crunchy]
select a, b from mytable where upper(a || '[' || b || ']') = upper('apple[crunchy]')
union all 
  select a, c from mytable where upper(a || '[' || c || ']') = upper('apple[crunchy]');
```

You can even create functional indexes on upper(a || '[' || b || ']') and upper(a || '[' || c || ']')

Comment: Thanks @mnesarco. Only thing is I'm using google sheets and I'm unsure as to how to implement your solution as I don't think it fully supports SQL. I'll give it a bash though.